# Font-weight is not working with any browser

Tags: html, css, fonts

My HTML file is :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Kitty Portfolio</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" class="img-responsive" alt="Logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-uppercase text-right">
          <h1 class="super-text">Jane Doette</h1>
          <h3>Front-end Ninja</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/1140x350" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2>Featured Work</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300" class="img-responsive">
          <h3>Appify</h3>
          <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300" class="img-responsive">
          <h3>Sunflower</h3>
          <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/555x300" class="img-responsive">
          <h3>Bokeh</h3>
          <p><a href="http://github.com">Link to project</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

And my css file is :-

```
.super-text {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: 200;
}


body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #747704;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

Now, When I open the html file in a browser. The font style and color makes it but the font-weight is nor affecting the any text on the screen. I tried mozilla firefox, chrome and internet explorer and none of these browsers do any good. Does anyone know where my problem might be lying.

Comment: Go to google.com/fonts select whatever font you need and check on the customize tab and include all the needed weights. For example this is the link tag for those font weight values
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">

Answer (score 0):

change font-eight in your CSS to 700px

Comment: I tried that and it worked but this only makes my font bolder. I dont understand that my font is getting bolder at 600, 700, 800, 900 but any value below 600 won't make it any lighter. Any idea why that is?

Comment: I am confused. What exactly you want to do, can you please explain

Answer (score 0):

i didn't encounter any problem with none of these 3 browsers but i got better results with

```
font-size: 60pt;
```

instead of using px in css file for size.

For font-weight don't use numbers, valid values are ;
 `normal|lighter|bold|bolder|value|initial| inherit`

Comment: I have the exact same words written on my css file and I can't see any thinness on the font. I don't know where I am going wrong. I posted a screenshot below just to make a point. Can you please help.

Comment: excuse me taimur, i confused with font-weight: 100 and 200 by rush. Now i've edited my answer. The important thing is to use "pt" instead of "px" just after "60" in the style.css file.

Comment: Its not working. I tried 700 and it worked but this only makes my font bolder. I dont understand that my font is getting bolder at 600, 700, 800, 900 but any value below 600 won't make it any lighter. Any idea why that is?

Comment: my Chrome version is 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit),
my Internet Explorer version 11.1358.14393.0,
my Firefox version is 54.0. There is no problem with boldness for none of the browsers for "Jane Doette", even if font-size : 50px, 60px ... 400px etc. in "super-text" class.